# How to exclude a value when comparing two columns for the max value in R

Tags: r, max

I have two columns: A and B, with values from 1 to 7 each. I need to get the maximum value between both columns EXCLUDING the value 7, how can I do that? OR In the case that A has 7 I keep the value of B, this would serve me more, for instance:

```
A <- c(1,1,1,3,2,4,2,5,6,7)
B <- c(7,3,6,7,4,1,6,7,3,4)
df <- data.frame(A, B)

Expected results: 1,3,6,3,4,4,6,5,6,4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option could be:

```
with(df, pmax(A * (A != 7), B * (B != 7)))

 [1] 1 3 6 3 4 4 6 5 6 4
```

To deal with missing values:

```
with(df, pmax(A * (A != 7), B * (B != 7), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Considering also negative values:

```
with(df, pmax(A * (A != 7)^NA, B * (B != 7)^NA, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Something important that I forget is that I have values with NA in one column and in the other I have a 3, for example, I need to stay with 3 and not NA

Comment: `pmax()` has a parameter to deal with missing values. See the updated post.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated** special thanks to dear @tmfmnk.

Maybe there is a better way of handling this problem but it instantly popped up in my mind to replace every 7 with the lowest possible value like 0 so that it does not affect the comparison. It also works with NA values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

A <- c(1,1,1,3,2,4,2,5,6,7)
B <- c(7,3,6,7,4,1,6,7,3,4)

df <- tibble(A, B)

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., . == 7, 0))) %>%
  mutate(ResultColumn = pmap_dbl(., ~ max(c(...), na.rm = TRUE)))


# A tibble: 10 x 3
       A     B ResultColumn
   <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
 1     1     0            1
 2     1     3            3
 3     1     6            6
 4     3     0            3
 5     2     4            4
 6     4     1            4
 7     2     6            6
 8     5     0            5
 9     6     3            6
10     0     4            4
```

Comment: Something important that I forget is that I have values with NA in one column and in the other I have a 3, for example, I need to stay with 3 and not NA.

Comment: @tmfmnk Thank you for your note, I used that because `str_replace` only accepts strings. But you were right thanks to `replace` it was possible. I edited my code.

Comment: @AgustínDamiani I edited my code so that it will exclude `NA`s.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the `tidyverse` example:

```
library(tidyverse)
A <- c(1,1,1,3,2,4,2,5,6,7)
B <- c(7,3,6,7,4,1,6,7,3,4)
        
df <- data.frame(A,B)
        
df %>% 
  filter(A != 7, B != 7) %>% 
  transform(ResultColumn = pmax(A,B))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You should not exclude any rows from comparison. Just if there is a 7 in any row the other value is automatically chosen.

Comment: oh I see, if they are trying to do some function my code won't be helpful. I should've written a general code - but it was already given by someone so

Comment: You can edit your code, it doesn't matter if there is already an answer. Cause every answer has its own value.

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `pmax`

```
> do.call(pmax, c(replace(df, df == 7, NA), na.rm = TRUE))
 [1] 1 3 6 3 4 4 6 5 6 4
```

or

```
> do.call(pmax, replace(df, df == 7, -Inf))
 [1] 1 3 6 3 4 4 6 5 6 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df$max <- ifelse(pmax(df$A,df$B)==7, pmin(df$A,df$B),pmax(df$A,df$B))
```